# peer to peer communication - java

Tags: java, client-server

I need to create a program where a peer needs to communicate with other peer. I have vaguely created a structure but it does not work. I know I am making a mistake but not able to  figure out the problem. I create a server socket as a thread and create a client socket thread which will talk to the server socket thread. after I enter a port, the program does nothing...

```
    server.java
    ------------
    class server
   {
       public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
       {

          //server socket
          ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1001);
          Socket client;
          while(true)
          {
            client = server.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(new acceptconnection(client));
            t.start();
          }
      }
   }

   class acceptconnection implements Runnable
   {
       BufferedReader inFromClient,inn;
       DataOutputStream ds;
       Socket clientsocket;
       acceptconnection (Socket socket) throws IOException
       {          
          this.clientsocket = socket;
          inn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          inFromClient =new BufferedReader(new                        
                        InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
          ds = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
      }

      @Override
      public void run ()
      {
         try 
         {
           String clientSentence, inp;
           while(( clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine())!=null)
           {                   
              System.out.println("message from remote socket #" +   
                 clientsocket.getRemoteSocketAddress()+ clientSentence);

              inp=inn.readLine();
              ds.writeBytes(inp + "\n");
              ds.flush();
           }
        }
     }
  }

   client.java
   ------------
   class client
   {
      public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {   
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        //  ss = new  ServerSocket(10002);
        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1001);

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new 
           InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new 
           DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new 
           InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Enter you name:"); 
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();  
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n" );  

        System.out.println("Enter the port u want:"); 
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();  
        int serverport = Integer.parseInt(sentence);

        Thread t = new Thread(new acceptconnection1(serverport));
        t.start();
        String msg;        

        clientSocket.close();
     }
  }

 class acceptconnection1 implements Runnable {
 BufferedReader inserver, inn; 
 DataOutputStream ds;
 Socket socket, peersocket;

         int serverport ;

      Socket clientSocket = null;
     acceptconnection1 (int serverport) throws IOException{   
     this.serverport = serverport;}

       public void run () {
     ServerSocket ss;


        String cs,a;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(serverport);

        while(true)
        {
        peersocket =ss.accept();

        Thread t = new Thread(new abc(peersocket) );
        t.start();
        }}}


      class abc implements Runnable {
BufferedReader inn,inp;
DataOutputStream ds;
   Socket peersocket;
public abc(Socket peersocket) throws IOException{
this.peersocket = peersocket;


inn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      inp =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(peersocket.getInputStream()));
  ds = new DataOutputStream(peersocket.getOutputStream());

}

@Override
public void run()
    {
   String clientSentence;

    Socket client = new Socket();
    try {
        while(( clientSentence = inp.readLine())!=null)
                {

                    ds.writeBytes("wake up!");
                    //System.out.println("message=" + clientSentence);

                }
```

Comment: so what is the  output , what is the error

Comment: can anyone tell how to make a client program act both as server and client? this is what I have tried.

Comment: can you post the output or error messages what are you getting?

Comment: satya, when i give the port no, the client program accepts it.. but after that, it does nothing... in the sense, the console remains as it is, without any error

Comment: server output - message from remote socket #/127.0.0.1:56685deepak
                message from remote socket #/127.0.0.1:56686ffff                  client deepak's output - Enter you name:
deepak
Enter the port u want:
4444                                                                      client ffff's output - Enter you name:
ffff
Enter the port u want:
5555

Comment: Please start by formatting the code - I do not even want to read it :-)

Comment: regarding the o/p - server output tells about the clients that registered with it - namely deepak and ffff.                              each client is asked a server socket # and the client enters it. after entering this, the program freezes...